# Flutter Location package requestService() never returns

Tags: flutter, dialog, gps, location, future

I have a function like this. Using Location package from flutter it shows the dialog to enable GPS.

```
  Future<bool> _checkServiceStatus() async {
    final Location location = Location();
    bool serviceStatus = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!serviceStatus) {
      serviceStatus = await location.requestService();
      print('status -> $serviceStatus');
    }
    return serviceStatus;
  }
```

When its calling **await location.requestService()**, it is showing the dialog to enable GPS but after that it never returns the result.
Even its not executing the **print()** function.

What am i doing wrong here?

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: print out `serviceStatus`. Maybe `if` code not executed?

Comment: the code is executed, i know for sure because it shows the GPS dialog.

Comment: I not familar with that plugin. It seems like you need set permission?

Comment: yes, it shows the dialog to enable my GPS 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Q4D.png
after that it just stops, the future never returns and next line never executes (print function)

Comment: Just clean and build your project.  May it is build issue. Same code working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It could be solved by upgrading your Flutter project, follow this link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to check wather permission enabled, service enabled than it returns true else false. Must configure "location" package related configuration in android and ios projects.

```
Future<bool> checkServiceStatus() async {
  final Location location = Location();
  final locationPermission = await location.hasPermission();
  if (locationPermission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
    final locationServiceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (locationServiceEnabled == true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      final requestServiceStatus = await location.requestService();
      if (requestServiceStatus == true) {
        return true;
      } else {
        BotToast.showSimpleNotification(
            title: "Enable GPS to allow this feature");
        return false;
      }
   }
  } else {
    BotToast.showSimpleNotification(title: "Required location permission to allow this feature");
    return false;
  } 
}
```